# whats the best way to allow users to edit a site wiki style

Tags: mysql, wiki

and have the changes save straight to the mysql db only requiring an email address to make the change

Comment: That's pretty vague.  Using what language - PHP, ASP, etc?

Comment: using php now.. but would re-write the site to fit the best answer and the best solution

Answer (score 4):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)?  It's a PHP app most commonly used with MySQL, and you can configure it to require (only) an email.